# Regex for php contains and not contains letters

Tags: php, regex

I have a array that looks like this:

```
[cspacer231]
[*spacer231]
[*spacer10]-
[*spacer2]
[*spacer3210]-
[cspacer2221]
```

Now, I want to take all `[*spacerNUMBER]` without the - at the end.
My try was this `"/\[\*spacer(.*?)](?!-)/"`, but it just takes the first child.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you storing values within `[]` braces

Comment: Did any of these answer helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
"/\[\*spacer(.*?)\]$/"
```

The `$` sign requires that there's nothing after `]`.

If you want to restrict to numbers after `spacer`:

```
"/\[\*spacer([0-9]*?)\]$/"
```

Comment: Thank you ! I love regex more and more

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
/\[.*spacer(.*?)](?!-)/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should be

```
\[\*spacer(\d+)\](?!-)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/wD5fM9/1

used in PHP:

```
$array = array('[cspacer231]',
'[*spacer231]',
'[*spacer10]-',
'[*spacer2]',
'[*spacer3210]-',
'[cspacer2221]');
foreach($array as $thing) {
     if(preg_match('~\[\*spacer(\d+)\](?!-)~', $thing, $match)) {
          echo $match[1] . "\n";
     }
}
```

Output:

```
231
2
```

You should use the `\d+` so you are sure it is a number and not just anything.